# Can't upload to PPA because of GPG signature

Tags: ppa, deb

I formated my PC and I'm trying to upload a new version on my app to my PPA. But I'm stuck with the next issue...

As you can see, I have my GPG key, I uploaded and confirmed in Launchpad:

```
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$ gpg --fingerprint
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$ gpg2 --fingerprint
/home/costales/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------
pub   rsa2048/A0E929E6 2017-06-01 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 41B4 81ED D84B AAC8 43E1  E72E 34DF 00C2 A0E9 29E6
uid         [ultimate] costales <costales.marcos@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048/959B785C 2017-06-01 [E]

costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$
```

I create the sources (system didn't ask for my private GPG password):

```
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$ dpkg-buildpackage -S -sa -rfakerootdpkg-buildpackage: source package anoise
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.0.26
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by costales <costales.marcos@gmail.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build anoise-0.0.26
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean 
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
pyversions: missing X(S)-Python-Version in control file, fall back to debian/pyversions
pyversions: missing debian/pyversions file, fall back to supported versions
    python setup.py clean -a
running clean
'build/lib.linux-i686-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/bdist.linux-i686' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  anoise.desktop.in
  po/anoise.pot
    find . -name \*.pyc -exec rm {} \+
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b anoise-0.0.26
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building anoise in anoise_0.0.26.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building anoise in anoise_0.0.26.dsc
 dpkg-genchanges -S -sa >../anoise_0.0.26_source.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build anoise-0.0.26
dpkg-buildpackage: source-only upload: Debian-native package
 signfile anoise_0.0.26.dsc

 signfile anoise_0.0.26_source.changes
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$
```

But I can't upload to my PPA:

```
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$ dput ppa:costales/anoise ../anoise_0.0.26_source.changes 
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made jue 01 jun 2017 22:14:13 CEST using RSA key ID A0E929E6
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Error verifying signature on ../anoise_0.0.26_source.changes.
costales@dev:~/Desktop/anoise-0.0.26$
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**ADDED:**

`anoise_0.0.26_source.changes`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24741506/

`dput --debug ppa:costales/anoise`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24741500/

Comment: Could you please include the content of `anoise_0.0.26_source.changes` and the output of `dput --debug ppa:costales/anoise` in your quest? That may uncover more info on what's happening here. You can also try to skip the signature check with `--unchecked`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added https://paste.ubuntu.com/24741500/ https://paste.ubuntu.com/24741506/ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please run `dput --debug ppa:costales/anoise` in the same working directory as in your question? Obviously the upload will fail if `dput` can't find a changes file. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sure :) https://paste.ubuntu.com/24748968/

Comment: @DavidFoerster The `--unchecked` flash on dput uploaded the package to the PPA. Thanks a lot mate! Could you reply as formal comment for my +1 :) A big hug!

Comment: That's more of a workaround than a solution. I'd have preferred to see the debug output but that won't be possible until you have something else to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason GnuPG doesn't find your own public key in your key ring when it tries to verify the signature on the changes file. I tried to run the verification myself successfully, so it's no malformed changes file or something like that.

As a workaround you can run `dput` with the `--unchecked` flag to skip the signature verification.